# It is possible to sort Email order confirmation by sku in both customer email notification and Admin email notification

Tags: magento2.3, email, sort, order-confirmation-email

I am on the m2 site. In order confirmation email I am getting SKU. But I need that SKU sort by ASC. Could someone assist me with this? Thanks in advance.

I have overridden the below file in my theme to get SKU in order confirmation email.
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the file **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml** in your theme add below code.

$_items = $_order->getAllItems();
$sortSKU = array();
foreach ($_items as $item) {
$sortSKU[$item->getSku()] = $item;
}
ksort($sortSKU);

And Insted of
foreach ($_items as $_item) use
foreach ($sortSKU as $_item)